# Reading name of father on German baptism record for Maria Magdalena Burkhardt Langenheld

Tags: germany, palaeography, german-language, transcriptions, kurrent

The excerpt here is from the baptism record of Maria Magdalena Burkhardt Langenheld, an illegitimate birth in 1779.  It transcribes as "(...)inn Langenheldin,  durch [?] er zeugtes Töchterlein, ist den 11. Sept".

[image: baptism record of Maria Magdalena Burkhardt Langenheld excerpt]

The left side is the original scan, and the right is photoshop enhanced to remove as much of the ink smear as possible.

For [?], the best I can transcribe it is a meaningless name, either 'Hurhery' or 'Gurhery'.  There are a couple dozen males who could have been possible fathers, but being 18th century Germany, there's actually not many distinct names for the possible fathers:

- Adam
- Andrais
- Christian
- Conrad
- Georg
- Gottfried
- Henrich
- Johann
- Malcolm
- Martin
- Michael
- Wilhelm

It's always possible that there was some other male I don't yet know of who was the father, but in this case, it'd be very very unlikely.

Can anyone read the [?] to figure out what name was written/intended?

Entire record:
[image: Entire record]

Comment: Could you add a larger snippet from the record? The context and other words might give important clues.

Comment: Sure, I've added the entire record.  It was an illegitimate birth/baptism's entry, so the original was written sideways, hence the narrowness of the entry's text.  I've reversed the rotation to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I deciphered the alleged father's name: it reads "Huhrerey", so harlotry or whoring (not sure what the corresponding English term in this context would be). As far as I can read the rest, there is only information about the mother and the godparents (I guess also from the mother's family).

Comment: Thanks; so not a name, but a condemnation by the priest.  Burkhardt is a local surname, so that's a hint towards the father, but unfortunately, that doesn't narrow it more than a couple dozen candidates.

Comment: ...and just for confirmation, I just now found another case from a couple decades earlier where the priest wrote a similar entry for another illegitimate child: "NB 22. Anna Cattharina, Eva Cattharina Burckharts Töchterl(ein) welches sie durch Huhrerey erzeugt ist d(en) 17 Juni getauft sein Taufpate ist Anna Catharina Matthesin, unverheiratete Person."